# pandas multiindex (hierarchical index) subtract columns and append result

Tags: python, pandas, append, multi-index, hierarchical

I have this bit of code which is working beautifully...

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import pandas as pd

myStartDate = '2020-12-15'   # (Format: Year-Month-Day)
myEndDate = '2020-12-31'   # (Format: Year-Month-Day)
myTickers = 'TSLA'
myData = pdr.get_data_yahoo(myTickers, myStartDate, myEndDate)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 200)

print(myData.head())
```

The result is:

```
           High     Low    Open    Close   Volume    Adj Close
Date                                                                             
20-12-15  646.90  623.79  643.28  633.25  45223600  633.250000
20-12-16  632.50  605.00  628.22  622.77  42095800  622.770020
20-12-17  658.82  619.50  628.19  655.90  56270100  655.900024
20-12-18  695.00  628.53  668.90  695.00  22212620  695.000000
20-12-21  668.50  646.07  666.23  649.85  58045300  649.859985
```

Then, I have this:

```
myData['Some New Column Name'] = myData['High'] - myData['Low']
print(myData.head())
```

And it works beautifully and the result is this:

```
           High     Low    Open    Close   Volume   Adj Close   Some New Column Name
Date                                                                                                   
20-12-15  646.90  623.79  643.28  633.25   45223600  633.25            23.10
20-12-16  632.50  605.00  628.22  622.77   42095800  622.77            27.50
20-12-17  658.82  619.50  628.19  655.90   56270100  655.90            39.32
20-12-18  695.00  628.53  668.90  695.00   22212620  695.00            66.46
20-12-21  668.50  646.07  666.23  649.85   58045300  649.85            22.42
```

I want to modify the code to do multiple "myTickers" like this:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import pandas as pd

myStartDate = '2020-12-15'   # (Format: Year-Month-Day)
myEndDate = '2020-12-31'   # (Format: Year-Month-Day)
myTickers = ['TSLA', 'SQ']
myData = pdr.get_data_yahoo(myTickers, myStartDate, myEndDate)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 200)

print(myData.head())
```

This works beautifully and the result is:

```
Attributes  Adj Close         Close            High            Low             Open           Volume    
Symbols    TSLA     SQ     TSLA     SQ     TSLA     SQ     TSLA     SQ     TSLA     SQ      TSLA    SQ
Date                                                
12/15/20  633.25  219.99  633.25  219.99  646.90  221.72  623.80  216.73  643.28  218.41  45223600  5713600
12/16/20  622.77  227.08  622.77  227.08  632.50  227.96  605.00  220.03  628.23  223.86  42095800  8216500
12/17/20  655.90  230.74  655.90  230.74  658.82  237.09  619.50  227.70  628.19  230.00  56270100  10440100
12/18/20  695.00  235.45  695.00  235.45  695.00  236.37  628.54  231.10  668.90  235.00  22212620  8099500
12/21/20  649.86  233.50  649.86  233.50  668.50  241.85  646.07  232.26  666.24  236.09  58045300  1115540
```

Similar to the first example, I want to do: (Tesla's high) - (Tesla's low) = (Some New Column Name) and (SQ's high) - (SQ's low) = (Some New Column Name) but I am not very experienced with pandas on how to do this. My understanding is that this is a multiindex or (hierarchical index) pandas dataframe. Reading some documentation, I thought something like this might work:

```
myData['Some New Column Name']['TSLA', 'SQ'] = myData['High'] - myData['Low']
```

or

```
myData[['Some New Column Name'],['TSLA', 'SQ']] = myData['High'] - myData['Low']
```

But this doesn't work... I feel like maybe it is close?

To be clear, I want something like this:

```
Attributes  Adj Close         Close       ...       Open            Volume      Some New Col
Symbols    TSLA     SQ     TSLA     SQ    ...   TSLA     SQ      TSLA     SQ     TSLA    SQ
Date                                      ...           
12/15/20  633.25  219.99  633.25  219.99  ...  643.28  218.41  45223600 5713600  23.10  4.99
12/16/20  622.77  227.08  622.77  227.08  ...  628.23  223.86  42095800 8216500  27.50  7.93
12/17/20  655.90  230.74  655.90  230.74  ...  628.19  230.00  56270100 1044010  39.32  9.39
12/18/20  695.00  235.45  695.00  235.45  ...  668.90  235.00  22212620 8099500  66.46  5.27
12/21/20  649.86  233.50  649.86  233.50  ...  666.24  236.09  58045300 1115540  22.43  9.59
```

I just tried:

```
myNewData = myData['High'] - myData['Low']
```

and the result is this:

```
Symbols          TSLA        SQ
Date                           
2020-12-15  23.100037  4.990005
2020-12-16  27.500000  7.930008
2020-12-17  39.320007  9.389999
2020-12-18  66.460022  5.269989
2020-12-21  22.429993  9.590012
```

I can probably work with this... But... It would be nice to append this to myData in some clean way instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were pretty close...

```py
myData[[('Some new column', c) for c in myData['High'].columns]] = myData['High'] - myData['Low']
```

Comment: ugh... Is there away to automatically populate the 'SQ' and 'TSLA' since it is already in the "myData" dataframe? Or somehow use the "myTickers" list? Because, I was only using these 2 ('SQ' and 'TSLA') to simplify things... In reality, I may have 30? or more? Keying them in individually over and over like this would be terrible... there must be a better way? However, thank you for your answer it definitely will get me by for now.

Comment: You can dynamically create the names of the columns to be added (i.e., `[('Some New Column Name', 'SQ'), ('Some New Column Name', 'TSLA')]`), looping over all the available ones, that you can get from the second level of `High` or `Low` (if I've understood your question correctly).

Comment: I think you are understanding correctly. Can you post an example of this type of loop?

Comment: Absolutely beautiful!! Thank you so much!!